# Trying to css change property values every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

```
$('.alphabetLetter').click(function() {
    if($(this).css('color') == 'black') {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':0.2},500);
    } else if($(this).css('opacity') == '0.2') {
        $(this).animate({
            'color':'#aa0000',
            'opacity':1
        },500);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({'color':'black'},500);
    }
});
```

I am trying to change between a black letter with an opacity of 1 to  a black letter with an opacity of 0.2 to a red letter with an opacity of 1 changing each time it clicks. This doesn't seem to be working and I am clueless as to why.

Comment: Perhaps we can see a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using rgb values instead of the color names.  jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8wTb/)

```
$('.alphabetLetter').click(function() {
    if($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':0.2},500);
    } else if($(this).css('opacity') == '0.2') {
        $(this).animate({
            'color':'#aa0000',
            'opacity':1
        },500);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({'color':'black'},500);
    }
});
```

NOTE: Your current logic will always only execute the first conditional statement because you're checking if the color = black, which it will always be - the `else if` won't ever run, even if the `opacity` = 0.2

Answer (score 0):

jQuery handles color properties via the RGB syntax. For more in depth information, please read http://api.jquery.com/css/.

I created a little fiddle just to clarify for you and others who stumble upon this question.

http://jsfiddle.net/dKXGJ/

As for your question here, you're checking for the string value `'black'` which will always return `false`. Always. You need to check for `rgb(0,0,0)` value.

A better and more detail fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dKXGJ/3/

Happy Coding, apply that syntax to your logic and you should be fine. :)